# 'MON-YY' DATE FORMAT VALIDATION IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting char datatype  date format from a procedure input parameter.
Example

```
create or replace procedure p_date(prd char)
AS
p_err exception;

BEGIN
IF prd <> 'MON-YY' THEN --what to write here to validate?
--where MON may be JAN-DEC any month and YY can be 00-99 --YEAR
raise p_err;
EXCEPTION
WHEN p_err THEN
DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid date format');
END;
```

assigned date - 'JAN-99'  valid
assigned date - 'JAN/99' OR ABD/89 or ABD-99 etc invalid
So any other format except MON-YY should be invalid. Also please take care of -(hyphen) we are not using slash between MON and YY.
Please help in validating date format without using REGEXP.Please suggest as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggestion: use the `TO_DATE` function

Answer (score 1):

You don't need exception handling for this.  You could use:

```
if (to_date(prd DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'MON-YY') is null)
begin
    . . .
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for help ,my requirement is raising exception if format is not valid do you have any other option.

Comment: You can leave out the `default on error` clause to generate an exception.  However, most people want to avoid exceptions if they are easily avoidable.

Comment: "Most people want to avoid exceptions" is probably true (sad as that is). Even more strongly, "most people what to **hide** exceptions" whenever they can. Using a default instead of throwing an error does not avoid the exception, it just hides it. What most people **should** want is that exceptions be raised to them, so that they can handle them properly rather than sweeping them under the carpet.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure p_date(prd char)
AS
  invalid_date_format exception;
  pragma exception_init(invalid_date_format, -1861);
  dt date;
BEGIN
  dt := to_date(prd, 'fxMON-YY');
EXCEPTION
  when invalid_date_format then
    dbms_output.put_line('Invalid date format: input must be in format MON-YY');
    raise;
END;
/
```

A few notes about this:

You can use the same in plain SQL, if you don't really need a procedure. (Maybe you do, maybe you don't - you didn't tell us why you were using one in the first place.)

The **fx** format model modifier in `to_date()` is crucial. Without it, `APRIL` would be accepted (even though the element is `MON`), slash would be accepted instead of dash, etc. "FX" stands for **f**ormat e**x**act, which is what you requested.

The procedure doesn't really do anything with the date. It seems more likely that you will want a function, not a procedure - one that returns the date if successful, and otherwise throws the same error.

I assumed that after the error message is printed, you still want the procedure to result in an error (and not be considered "completed successfully" just because the error was handled). This is what the `raise` statement does in the `EXCEPTION` section.

Here is how the procedure works; notice that I turn on server output first, otherwise the procedure still throws the error but the error message stays in the output buffer without ever making it to my screen.

```
set serveroutput on

exec p_date('APRIL-99')

Invalid date format: input must be in format MON-YY


Error starting at line : 36 in command -
BEGIN p_date('APRIL-99'); END;
Error report -
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at "MATHGUY.P_DATE", line 11
ORA-06512: at "MATHGUY.P_DATE", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
```

Comment: mathguy thanks for your effort , actually we are migrating an old procedure so we can not opt function.your procedure is correct but it should always throw invalid_date_format exception for  any type of invalid format  ex 'ABD-99',APR/99 etc

Comment: It does throw exactly that exception for APR/99 (I already said that in my answer). It throws a different exception - "invalid month" - for ABD-99, because that is actually in the correct format, but ABD is simply an invalid month. Do you want the procedure to throw an invalid **format** error when in fact the format is 100% correct, but the month is invalid? It can be done, but that is a very odd requirement - it will give you (and your users, and the support workers) incorrect information, hiding the true problem.

Comment: Do you want the procedure to throw an invalid format error when in fact the format is 100% correct, but the month is invalid? and also when '/' or any other symbol is used for '-'(hyphen)  -- Yes please get me the code , I want to raise user define exception only  in all cases . Thanks again for being with me

Comment: What does "in all cases" mean? Even if the program runs out of memory, for example? If you want to catch **all** possible errors and trow just one user-defined error message, the simplest way is to use `when others then` in the `exception` section. That is an exceptionally bad practice, but if you must display the same error message to the user in all cases, that's the way to do it. Much simpler than what I wrote, but very similar.